# How can I make sure that my JavaScript files delivered over a CDN are not altered?

Tags: javascript, code-signing

I am working on a scenario in which some JavaScript files are to be hosted on a CDN. I want to have some mechanism so that when these file are downloaded on user side, I can ensure that the files were not tampered with and are indeed coming from the specified CDN.

I understand that the task is very easy if I am using SSL, but still, I want to ensure that the right files are served even on HTTP without SSL.

As far as I could search, there is no existing mechanism like digital signature for JavaScript files which is supported across platforms. Perhaps it's not needed?

Is there some method built in to browsers to verify the author of the JavaScript files? Is there anything I can do to do this in a secure way?

Comment: Whilst I find this question interesting, is it not off-topic?

Comment: why would you serve files on http?

Comment: "But why there is no such mechanism?" Because it's _really hard_. Once your data has left your server, it's toast. HTTPS helps but if it's a plain HTTP connection any validation can fail (or rather - pass). A MITM attack can just modify your expected signature and/or the signature of what you're provided with before the browser gets ahold of the expectations. So, when the user receives some payload it'd be deemed completely safe...when it's not necessarily that.

Comment: @Vld: If there were a convention that requests that included a pair of base64 strings formatted a certain way would validate that the referenced file included a public key whose hash matched the first string, an ID which matched the second, and a signature using the indicated public key that validated the ID along with the JS content, would a MITM attack be able to alter anything without the change being detectable, other than by reverse-engineering the hash or signature (which for quality hash/signature algorithms should be intractable)?

Comment: @supercat "If there were a convention..." which is part of why it's hard. To answer your question - I don't know. I'd say "probably". It may be hard to modify arbitrary files, but the thing is, you don't need to reverse engineer and modify ALL files. As soon as you have one (or 10) you can infect a very large number of pages. Say, there is a MITM and the attacked has only cracked the key for jQuery. Having all the rest of your files safe is irrelevant as a malicious payload can be slipped with jQuery.

Comment: "But why there is no such mechanism?"  Because there's already a cheap, effective, and broadly applicable solution in HTTPS.

Comment: @supercat Such a thing already exists.  It's called TLS (admittedly, the technical details differ from your description).

Comment: @Brian: It sounds like the "integrity" attribute serves the indicated purpose; unlike TLS, it would not impede caching by proxy servers.

Comment: This should probably be on ServerFault or Security, as it's really about serving files in a secure way, and any relation to programming is only tangential inasmuch as said files happen to represent source code.

Comment: Actually Microsoft's JScript did support digital signatures (Authenticode); I'm not sure why that didn't become more widespread in other engines.

Comment: @supercat Perhaps, but it's a very narrow case.  It's only helpful when your HTML file is served via https and your javascript is served via http from a CDN, and in that case Firefox will block your javascript (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content)

Comment: @Brian: That ties in with another advantage of including the expected hash in the request (URL): if a new version of a JS library comes out which adds features to an old one but should be compatible, posting it under the same name would break any references that contain hashes.  Having the hash be part of the name would make it easy to have code which expects the old version, receive the old version.

Comment: When the Internet was born, there was huge trust and basically no security. The security came later.

Comment: @immibis which? client side caching does not care about the protocol. Server-side caching neither, that leaves proxys and in-between servers. Do you actually trust those to properly and safely cache your content?

Comment: @njzk2 With sub-resource integrity... yes?

Comment: @immibis not all browsers support it, which means some of your users are still at risk. Plus that's not enough. Even if the browser rejects an invalid resource, it still means the user did not receive that resource.

Comment: @njzk2 A MITM can prevent your browser receiving resources even with HTTPS. It also wouldn't be the first time a new browser feature was required for security - in previous cases, people were told that any security problems are their fault for not keeping their browser updated.

Comment: @immibis but a mitm can't try to inject other resources instead (unless other issue out of the scope of this question). And when I say some browser don't support SRI, I mean the latest version of the 2 browsers shipped with the 2 most commonly used OSes. You can't really say to people: "please change your browser because I don't want to use https because it prevents hypothetical caching from third party servers on the way". hypothetical caching you don't need if you use proper CDN.

Comment: @njzk2 In a few years, the latest version of the 2 browsers shipped with the 2 most commonly used OSes will support SRI. Just like every other web technology so far.

Comment: @immibis great! meanwhile, use https.

Comment: @njzk2 Nobody said they weren't going to use HTTPS, right now, because of subresource integrity. We are talking about hypothetical future situations here.

Comment: @immibis I am not sure what you mean. I was never talking about any future situation. The OP explicitly wrote: "I want to ensure that the right files are served even on HTTP without SSL." That counts as not using https to me.

Answer (score 141):

As a matter of fact, a feature like this is [currently being drafted](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-subresource-integrity/) under the name of *Subresource Integrity*. **Look into the `integrity` attribute of the `<script>` tag.** [While not yet fully adopted across the board](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity#Browser_compatibility), it fulfills just this purpose.

> **`integrity`**
>
> Contains inline metadata that a user agent can use to verify that a fetched resource has been delivered free of unexpected manipulation. See Subresource Integrity.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes)

> Subresource Integrity (SRI) is a security feature that enables browsers to verify that files they fetch (for example, from a CDN) are delivered without unexpected manipulation. It works by allowing you to provide a cryptographic hash that a fetched file must match.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity)

---

**Example:**

```
<script src="https://example.com/example-framework.js"
    integrity="sha384-oqVuAfXRKap7fdgcCY5uykM6+R9GqQ8K/uxy9rx7HNQlGYl1kPzQho1wx4JwY8wC"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

Note however that this **will not protect you against [Man in the Middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)** if you are transferring your resources via plain HTTP. In this case, the hash code can be spoofed by the attacker, rendering the defense against manipulated script files useless.

For this reason, you should always use secure HTTPS connections instead of plain HTTP in addition to the security measures described above.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the integrity check can easily be spoofed assuming that OP plans to send their HTML in HTTP as well as their asset files. If their site is HTTPS and they want to serve assets via HTTP then most browsers are not going to like this and silently ignore the HTTP assets.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus This would only be true though in case of an MITM attack or if our own server is compromised, correct? My understanding is that the question explicitly asks how to defend against a compromised CDN.

Comment: @TimoSta Exactly! Without these checks in place, if you include a script from, for example, `https://code.jquery.com/`, then anyone who compromises `code.jquery.com` can XSS your site, regardless of whether or not `code.jquery.com` is being accessed over HTTPS. With these checks in place the attacker can only prevent the scripts from loading, not replace them with malicious ones.

Comment: @TimoSta You are correct about what the question is asking explicitly but I think it is still worth mentioning that your answer is for OP's explicit situation because future readers may not be so keen on the devil in the details.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I added a note to my answer, stating your concerns. Do you agree with the wording?

Comment: @TimoSta Very nice, I like it! btw, I did +1 even before I posted my first comment :-)

Comment: BTW, this feature is used on github.com.

Comment: Wait... MITM where? The hash can only be spoofed if the user is not actually coming to your main page (in which case, all bets are off). However, if an attacker somehow intercepts the resources requests, or corrupts the resources on the 3rd party site, then the hash the browser computes should differ. How would you spoof it?

Comment: @Ajedi32 "With these checks in place the attacker can only prevent the scripts from loading, not replace them with malicious ones." So, that means that if somebody compromises `code.jquery.com` then _all sites referencing it will stop working_. Who cares that a (potentially) malicious payload was prevented, when you've replaced it with a very efficient DoS.

Comment: @Vld That's still a far easier scenario to recover from than a successful XSS attack. The former situation is "oops, my site is down for a couple hours while I switch CDNs", the latter is "all my user's plaintext passwords just got stolen by a script when they signed in".

Comment: Point is - if you're not trusting the CDN _anyway_ the checksum is a bit of a false sense of security, since it acts as a different form of an attack vector.

Answer (score 36):

You're looking for [subresource integrity](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/) checks.

For example, here's the jQuery CDN snippet:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Totally useless because an attacker can modify the integrity field at the same time they modify the script you're downloading.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Not if you control your own domain which is accessed over HTTPS but do not control `code.jquery.com`. This can protect you from a compromised `code.jquery.com`.

Comment: @SilverlightFox: Okay, totally useless against MITM attacks*

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes. Still very useful and would have prevented this attack for example: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/twilio-exposes-sdk-attackers-inject-it-with-malvertising-code/

Answer (score 6):

*Disclaimer: As always, you should only consider these mechanisms to be of any use when using https, as they can easily be disabled via MitM with http*

In addition to the mechanism in the above answers, you can also use the **content-security policy** http response headers on the parent page.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/

> Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'sha256-qznLcsROx4GACP2dm0UCKCzCG-HiZ1guq6ZZDob_Tng='
>
> There are a few things to note here. The sha*- prefix specifies the algorithm used to generate the hash. In the example above, sha256- is used. CSP also supports sha384- and sha512-. When generating the hash do not include the  tags. Also capitalization and whitespace matter, including leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> Using Chrome 40 or later you can open DevTools then reload your page. The Console tab will contain error messages with the correct sha256 hash for each of your inline scripts.

This mechanism has been around for quite some time, so the browser support is likely pretty good, just be sure to check.

Additionally, if you want to ensure that older non-compliant browsers are not insecure, you can include a synchronous redirect script at the top of the page that is not allowed by the policy.

Comment: has been around for quite some time, but browser support isn't pretty good. http://caniuse.com/subresource-integrity

Comment: @Sp0t - Subresource integrity (what your link is about) is the mechanism in the other answers.  My answer is about content security policy, which has much better support

Answer (score 3):

There's an important point about what this kind of signing can and cannot do.  It *can* protect the user from hypothetical attacks in which someone modifies your code.  It *cannot* assure your site that your code is the code being executed.  In other words, you still can't trust anything that comes to your site from the client.

Answer (score 2):

If your adversary model permits an attacker to modify JavaScript files as they are delivered from a CDN, then your adversary model permits an attacker to modify the referring source as it is delivered to remove any attempt at verification, to alter the source address to other than the CDN, and/or to remove the reference to the JavaScript entirely.

And lets not open the can of worms of how your application can determine whether the user's resolver is or is not correctly resolving to the CDN via HTTP requests (or any other mechanism that doesn't have a verified chain of trust).

/etc/hosts:

```
#  ...
1.2.3.4    vile-pirates.org    trustworthy.cdn
#  ...
```

Comment: The first sentence is plainly untrue. What if the referring page is loaded over HTTPS and the JavaScript file is loaded over HTTP-not-S?

Comment: Or what if the CDN itself is compromised, but not your own server?

Comment: @immibis : I choose to assume OP is not so irrational as to propose such a scenario.

Comment: @immibis Isn't that why browsers generally don't allow HTTPS pages to load JS over HTTP?

Comment: @Barmar Well, *if* you have sub-resource integrity, then you can do exactly that safely!

Comment: @immibis Good point. I wonder if browsers turn off the HTTPS->HTTP check when SRI is used.

Comment: @Barmar You and Eric seemed to be saying "This feature is useless, because it only improves a particular configuration, and nobody will ever use that configuration because it's bad." without considering that with this feature perhaps they might.

Comment: @immibis I was saying that it improves a situation that's not even possible, because browsers disallow it.

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure this with Subresource Integrity. Many public CDNs include SRI hashes in the embeddable code offered on CDN websites. For example, on PageCDN, when you click on jquery file on the [jQuery CDN](https://pagecdn.com/lib/jquery) page, you get the option to either copy the URL or use the script tag that contains SRI hash as below:

```
<script src="https://pagecdn.io/lib/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

On page load, browser will issue a request for this resource and on completion of request it will match the hash of the received file with the one given as the integrity value in script tag. If both hashes do not match, browser will discard the jquery file.

At the moment, this feature is supported by 91% of browsers worldwide. More details on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=subresource-integrity).