# Is Subresource Integrity any useful for inline JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, subresource-integrity

I'm reading about Subresource Integrity and understand it's meant for verifying external files.  I guess it's no surprise I couldn't find any reference to inline JavaScript from either [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) or [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/).

So, is it safe to say that the SRI-related attributes, `integrity` and `crossorigin`, are completely useless for inline JavaScript ?

Comment: Related post - [How can I make sure that my JavaScript files delivered over a CDN are not altered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38700923/465053)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, is it safe to say that the SRI-related attributes `integrity` and `crossorigin` are completely useless for inline JavaScript?

Yes, because those attributes are only useful for a `script` element that has a `src` attribute:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-integrity

> The `integrity` attribute represents the integrity metadata for requests which this element is responsible for. The value is text. The `integrity` attribute must not be specified when embedding a module script or when the `src` attribute is not specified. [SRI]

Also as noted in the question, that’s also made clear by the description in MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity

> Subresource Integrity (SRI) is a security feature that enables browsers to verify that **files** they fetch (for example, from a CDN) are delivered without unexpected manipulation. It works by allowing you to provide a cryptographic hash that **a fetched file** must match.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for protecting inline script files you can use the [nonce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) attribute in CSP headers and specify that on the script tag

> nonce-base64-value
>   A whitelist for specific inline scripts using a cryptographic nonce (number used once). The server must generate a unique nonce value each time it transmits a policy. It is critical to provide an unguessable nonce, as bypassing a resource’s policy is otherwise trivial. See unsafe inline script for an example. Specifying nonce makes a modern browser ignore 'unsafe-inline' which could still be set for older browsers without nonce support.

Answer (score 2):

I know that the thread is a little bit older, but the integrity hash check is now supported by the W3C. The script is executed if:

- the src is set, the integrity attributes is correct AND matches the CSP policy
- the src is not set, the integrity attribute is correct OR matches the CSP policy

[Pull request](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-subresource-integrity/pull/86)

[WebAppSec Subresource Integrity](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-subresource-integrity/)

---

**EDIT:**
seems that actually only Chrome support this functionality

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe to say that, because the `integrity` attribute of a `<script>` tag is ignored when the `<script>` has no "src" attribute. SRI only comes into the picture when a resources is fetched via a separate HTTP request.