# How to digitally sign or verify third party javascript files?

Tags: javascript, jwt, public-key-encryption

### The Problem

We want to be able to securely add third party javascripts into our site to enable functionality. This could be Google Tag Manager, AppCues, MixPanel, etc. Third party javascript may be hosted on a third party site or CDN. These domains are not owned by us and should not be inherently trusted - because as we know, if they are hacked, that means when we include this code, our site is now owned.

### SubResource Integrity

The W3C (and browsers) have attempted to address this issue with [SubResource Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity). This works well for libraries that are well versioned. When you update the version, you update the integrity hash. However, this works terribly for javascripts like GTM, or Mixpanel that want to provide seamless updates and have constantly changing integrity hashes.

### Proposals

Its very surprising this issue is not well solved in 2021. There are some academic approaches to this [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s42452-019-1805-5) and [here](https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/%7Eenricob/2015/ccs15.pdf) that discuss using signatures to solve this issue. There is even an approach to solving this using blockchain [here](https://webboot.org)!

### The question

So, am I missing something? Is there a more recognized way to solve the security of including third party javascripts? We solved signing files, and software libraries, why can't we digitally sign javascripts? Could JWT or PGP/GPG be used?

In particular, I am wondering if there is a strategy that could leverage some basic coordination between the 3rd party javascript author and the including code. For instance, could the 3rd party author publish integrity hashes that were signed, so we as the including application could pull signed hashes and validate them?

### UPDATE

This is related to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700923/how-can-i-make-sure-that-my-javascript-files-delivered-over-a-cdn-are-not-altere) back in 2016 before SRI was fully adopted. This question is the 2021 version. I believe this to be a relevant question in 2021 because of the advent of SaaS services which were not as prevalent in 2016. Many of these services provide hosted javascript files and specifically do not version them because they want to provide constant updates.

Comment: Probably not. SubResource Integrity is the state of the art. Your question feels like it's suggesting a future, not yet achieved, state of web security. For services that defy SRI, maybe cache a particular version and use that signature.

Comment: You are not wrong. But as an engineer, there is part of me that refuses to accept the problematic status quo and I'm trying to see if there is an idea that can rely on 3p + application coordination using existing technologies (jwt, pgp, code signing, etc) to solve this until the w3c and browsers catch up.

Comment: They could sign them, yes, and you could verify that signature. Although it is a heavier weight solution performance and storage-wise, and much more complex, I was always surprised that signatures weren't at least an option for subresource integrity. It likely has some other negative consequence that I'm just missing.